# Prove that if {$A\overrightarrow{v}_{1},...,A\overrightarrow{v}_{k}$} is linearly independent, then B is linearly independent.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing

Suppose that A is an $n \times n$ matrix and B = {$\overrightarrow{v}_{1},...,\overrightarrow{v}_{k}$} $\subset R^n$. Prove that if {$A\overrightarrow{v}_{1},...,A\overrightarrow{v}_{k}$} is linearly independent, then B is linearly independent.

So I know how to prove it the other way, such that if B is linearly independent then {$A\overrightarrow{v}_{1},...,A\overrightarrow{v}_{k}$} is linearly independent but I'm not sure how to prove it the required way.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: The direction you say you know how to prove isn't actually true in general

Comment: Does the notation $\{\ldots\}$ stand for a set or something else?

Comment: Oh? Do you mind explaining to be why that is

Comment: It stands for a set yes

Comment: @Sania If $A$ is the null map, then $\left\{A\vec{v_1},\ldots,A\vec{v_n}\right\}$ is linearly dependent.

Comment: @Sanja Then the claim is not true. Consider $n=2$, $k=3$ $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}$, $\vec v_1=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}$, $\vec v_2=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}$, , $\vec v_3=\begin{pmatrix}2\\-1\end{pmatrix}$. This makes $\{A\vec v_1,A\vec v_2,A\vec v_3\}=\{\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix} \}$ is linearly independent, but $\{\vec v_1,\vec v_2,\vec v_3\}$ is not.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**: As always, start with the obligatory sentence. You want to prove $B$ is linearly independent, so you write

Suppose $c_1\vec v_1+\dots+c_k\vec v_k = \vec 0$. We must show $c_1=\dots=c_k=0$.

What is the obvious thing to do with the equation you have written down?

And, to emphasize what has been said in other comments, the converse is *false*. You need an additional hypothesis on $A$ for it to work. What hypothesis is that?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\alpha = \{Av_1, \dots, Av_k\}$ and $U = \text{span}\{B\}$.
Notice that $A(U) = \text{span}\{\alpha\}$.

Consider the restriction of $A$ given by $\widetilde{A}:U\longrightarrow A(U)$.
If $\alpha$ is linearly independent, then $\dim\big( A(U) \big)= k$.
Since $\dim (U)\leqslant |B| = k$, it follows from the rank-nullity theorem that $\dim(U) = k$ $($and that $\dim(\ker \widetilde{A}) = 0)$.

In other words, we have $\dim(\text{span}\{B\})  = |B|$, so $B$ must be linearly independent.